# PHP, Angular, HTACCESS - allow requests only from the origin domain

Tags: php, angular, .htaccess, cross-domain

I finished my Angular project. 
In my project I send POST requests with data to PHP files, and then get result from them back to Angular.

Now I want to allow requests only from the origin domain, and deny any request from any othe domain.
I try to use:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: example.com");
```

but it does not work. And I don't want to use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFFER'] because it can manipulated.
I also tried to use .HTACCESS but I don't know how to implement that. I tried something like that:

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from mydomain.com
```

but it does not work.

My project already has the following .HTACCESS file:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

taken from here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml
What can I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Is the minimum that should work (on your **server** side), but you may need to add two additional headers like:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
```

Like any `header()` call, be sure to perform those BEFORE any output.

---

Long answer:

CORS allow, with a relative security, to perform cross origin queries, depending on a pre-flight request OPTIONS to check what's allowed and what's not.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` sets which origins (domains) are allowed. You may want to use only your trusted domains.

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods` sets which methods are allowed. Usually, a lot of those.

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers` sets which optional (and customized) headers are allowed. Usually, you want to include any non-standard headers on top of Content-type.

CORS is incredibly well documented here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: I want to deny requests from any other domain which is not my domain. I try to use Access-Control-Allow-Origin: mydomain.com, but it does noy work... I want any request from any other will be rejected.

Comment: Check my long answer below, then; most of times, it is because there is still missing a header or that the method was not flagged properly in the method headers. CORS error in Javascript console usually tells you which thing fails : domain, method or header. Also, you can double check your OPTIONS request in most of modern browsers network tool... excepted Chrome, for some obscure reason.

Comment: Still does not work... I can easily use cURL to send POST request to my website, and get a result.

Comment: CORS restrictions apply to browsers only in the first place, they have _nothing whatsoever_ to do with other clients such a cURL requesting your data _outside_ the context of a website.